# How to merge a branch that is not created of Master into Master in GIT

Tags: git, git-merge

I created a branch ReleaseB from a commit off ReleaseA. ReleaseA was never merged into Master, but ReleaseA code is moved to PROD. So I took the PROD release commit off ReleaseA and created branch ReleaseB. What is the best way to merge ReleaseB to Master or bring Master uptodate with ReleaseB? Can I just checkout master and replace the contents with Release B branch?

Comment: What's wrong with just merging?

Comment: Merging ReleaseB to A looks good. But merging ReleaseB to Master has too many conflicts. I just want to make master clean so that the future branches would be created off master.

Comment: If you have conflicts, then you need to resolve the conflicts.  There's no way around that.

Comment: I tried this with one repo. I merged Release B to Master resolving all the conflicts, it took me almost 3 hours. I have 6 more Repos to go. But now when I want to pull changes from Master to Release A, it shows me all the conflicts I resolved earlier. But the merge from Release B to Release A looks clean. So I believe there should be a better of doing this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - why do you want to merge B into master and then **back** into A?  Can you talk about what end state you want?

Comment: Although Release A is pushed to PROD we still have active development on this branch. I created Release B off of A to work on a release that will be moved PROD before Release A. I want to merge Release B work into Release A through Master. ReleaseB --> Master --> ReleaseA, so that future branches could be created off Master.  Now the problem is even after merging Release B to master(after resolving a lot of conflicts), merging master to Release A shows a bunch conflicts. My desired state is Master should be up to date with Release B and then merge Master into Release A

Comment: The cost of using a workflow with multiple long-lived branches that each have active development is that you will have to perform excessive amounts of conflict resolution over time.  This is why models like git-flow are popular.  The "easier way" that it seems there must be is to never get into the state you're in, sorry to say.  You can avoid this in the future by reviewing your branch/merge strategy, but for now I don't see any choice but to perform the required conflict resolution, time-consuming though it is.

Comment: Thank you. I agree the branching strategy is messed up here. I am trying to fix this and make Master clean.

Comment: But my question here is once I merged B(which is created from A) to master, why would I see all conflicts again when merging from master to A. This merge should only contain the diff between A and B correct?

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways may be to cherry pick each commit one by one that branch into master.

Just go into your branch. `git log` will show you the commits with hashes.
Just copy them (hashes) and apply to master in order from oldest to younger.
to apply:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <hash>
```

Comment: I followed these steps to replace master with releaseB as releaseB is PROD.    git checkout releaseB
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge releaseB

Comment: your solution is also works, and sometimes it is even simpler and preferable (especially when you deal with a big amount of commits). The way with cherry-pick just give you more control what you are doing.